# Ubuntu bootable Usb

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

So I created a bootable Ubuntu pendrive. When I reboot, it just goes straight to Windows. Same thing if I boot from UEFI or if I change the boot order to external. It just won't do anything. I'm running Windows 10 and want to dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 (I think that's the one). Thanks!

EDIT: I downloaded the latest build of Ubuntu, been hearing about 14.04 not working on some Windows 10 computers (if not all). I tried booting into Legacy, and it worked...sorta. It showed me the installation options, but as soon as I typed something, it would report an error, and then I would be stuck in a terminal with no way to access anything. Reverted back to windows to download the latest build. I'll let you guys know if it works.

EDIT EDIT EDIT: After updating, it seems it is working. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: How did you create the bootable pendrive? And did you check the md5/sha1 checksum of the image file?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that whenever I install from USB, I have to select it as a Hard Drive option in the BIOS. This is probably the case for you if the name of the USB doesn't appear in the listing for external devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to your UEFI settings and specifically tell it to boot from the USB stick only.  If you change the boot order and something else is wrong with your USB stick (like it's missing its UEFI boot loader) it'll just skip it...

Unfortunately, UEFI settings are vendor-dependent so I can't tell you what to press exactly and what menu to go to, but I'm betting it's in the <kbd>Advanced Settings</kbd>.

Comment: It's mostly in Advanced Settings :)

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a key like `F2` which you can press right when you start your computer to be shown all boot media available. You should find your USB pen drive there and be able to select it.

If you get this dialog but your USB stick doesn't appear, Ubuntu probably isn't put onto the USB stick properly.

Make sure there only exists 1 partition on the USB stick. Some systems have problems with more than 1 partition existing when booting from a USB pen drive, others don't. Format this partition with FAT32 (make sure it is this FS!) and put on Ubuntu again.

Also, make sure that booting form external / usb is enabled in the bios settings.

Comment: I'll try this, it's the most likely answer. I'm working right now, so I'll let you know if it worked when I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: [F2] is a BIOS option: he's running in UEFI mode...  It needs to be done in UEFI...

Answer (score 0):

UEFI only detects FAT32 flash drives. Use LinuxLive USB Creator to create a FAT32 live USB. Then from Windows 10 Advanced Recovery Settings boot into the advanced boot menu. Go to Troubleshoot. Then choose "Use device UEFI USB". That's it. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663589/dual-booting-windows-10-and-ubuntu)

In the above link, I answered how I was able to create a dual-boot a laptop to an HDD with Windows 10 and a Flash drive to Ubuntu. I installed in UEFI mode with security turned off, but I boot in UEFI with security turned on.